# Loading PDF file/url shows black screen in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, safari

The Following javascript code are used in my application to open the PDF file in new window, from the parent page.

onclick="window.open("myurl.pdf","Terms_and_Conditions","height=800,width=1000,dependent=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");"

I have tested in 5.1.4 version of Safari browser. It shows a blank black screen. Then,If i click/focus the window, the PDF content was loaded.

Please guide me to resolve. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indent your code four spaces so it will be properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you use an href with `target="_blank"` instead of javascript to do this? That way it would work even if the user has JS disabled.